# How can I make ZXing Barcode Scanner compatible with 2.2 and above Android

Tags: java, android, zxing, backwards-compatibility

I want ZXing Barcode Scanner compatible with android 2.2 and above.

What I did - I used Zing 2.3.0 in my application and its perfectly working in 4.0 and above

but when I run in android 2.2 and I click the button to start scanner the application got crashed.

What extra I need to implement ??

Note: I have added `CaptureActivity project` from zxing as a library in my project and CaptureActivity and MyProject in both the menifest file minsdk is 8 and targeted is 17

Comment: "the application got crashed" -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has not been written for Android 2.2 compatibility in a long time. You can go back further to find such a version. But I would encourage you to write your own app and just reuse the core library instead. Also there are very few Android 2.2 devices anymore, less than 1%. It is not really worth supporting.

Comment: Hi Sean.. Thanks for reply .. But my client need that :( so any guidance how can I achieve that using zxing.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer sorry, but [zxing-android-minimal](https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal) was available when you asked your question!

It's a port of (the great) zxing but supports Android 7+.